# Is it possible to clip a Win32 window to a single monitor?

Tags: windows, winapi, clipping

Meaning that if I have several monitors, I would like the window to be painted in only one monitor and "not exist" on all the other monitors. I tried messing with `WM_NCPAINT` etc. but that only allows you to paint the frame differently, it doesn't allow you to hide it (preferably with the window shadow).

I'm playing with the idea of a window that you can spread over several monitors with different DPIs. Right now this is not possible (when 50% of a window is on a new monitor Windows "snaps" the window to the new DPI). On MacOS it draws a new window and displays both windows but in portions, the right DPI for the right monitor, and it's very smooth, none of the spastic snapping of Windows. But MacOS won't let you keep a window stretched across those two monitors. I want to see if I can emulate this behavior but allow a window to be stretched across a multi-monitor multi-DPI desktop.

I can freely scale my UI so that's not an issue, and the idea is to have in each of my Window objects an array of `std::tuple<Monitor&, HWND>` or something, one for each monitor, with `EnableNonClientDpiScaling()` etc., draw the appropriate and correctly scaled region into each HWND and then `DeferWindowPos()` to move all the HWNDs at once.

But I can try this only if it's possible to show each HWND on only one monitor, and so far no luck.

Comment: Trying to fight the system seems like a recipe for pain, with no prospect of any gain. Why not make your app fit in to the platform norms?

Comment: Why not address the question instead of philosophy? Sorry, but this is literally the worst kind of answer on here. "Oh, you want to learn how to do something specific? Don't be silly, you should replace your entire paradigm instead." My app already works within the norms, I'm just trying to see if it's possible to improve the situation. What's wrong with a little practical thought experiment? Dream a little, jeez.

Comment: Well, good luck making the system fit to your norms.

Comment: Look at [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653.aspx), [`WM_SIZING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647.aspx), [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626.aspx), etc.